# How to use CnosDB to calculate rate value？

Tags: cnosdb

I'm currently attempting to calculate rates within CnosDB (or a similar database) and encountering some difficulties. My goal is to compute the frequency of a specific event over a certain period, such as the occurrences per minute. Despite trying a few approaches, I'm still not getting the correct results.

The database table I'm working with consists of the following columns: timestamp and event_count. I'm looking to calculate the rate of change in the event count over specific time intervals to derive the event occurrence rate.

I've experimented with using window functions in my queries, but the outcomes seem inaccurate. Here's an example of what I've tried:

```
SELECT 
    timestamp,
    event_count - LAG(event_count) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) AS event_change
FROM 
    my_table
WHERE 
    timestamp >= [start_time] AND timestamp <= [end_time]
```

I've also attempted to use subqueries to calculate the total event count within the time interval, then divide it by the length of the interval. However, this approach also appears to yield inaccurate results.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide an effective method for calculating event rates within CnosDB (or a similar database).